# Wordpress on Docker (Synology NAS) with different networks

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, synology

first, sorry for my bad english, hope you can understand me.

i have the following task.

I want to run a (maybe more) wordpress installation on my synology nas. Therefore, i installed Docker and run  portainer for creating some stuff.

My main idea is to create the following:

- Create different container with separated wordpress installations
- Create mysql container for hosting the different wordpress databases, each for every wordpress app
- for the wordpress container there is a own network called "app_network" (bridge, attachable)
- for the mysql container there is another network called "db_backend" (bridge, attachable)

So far, so god. At the moment i created one WP container, the mysql container and the two networks. Everything seems to be fine.

- wordpress container is created with docker-compose (stack in portainer)

- mysql container is created with docker-compose (stack in portainer)

- I created a db for wordpress in the mysql container manually - local login on container works perfect.
- the mysql container is in the network db_backend
- the woordpress container is in the network app_network and additionally connected to the db_backend network (assigend ip´s looks correct)

But...if i am calling the wordpress page i got "Error establishing a database connection"

My yaml looks like this:

```
#mysql.yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:latest
     restart: on-failure:3
     volumes:
       - /volume1/docker/databases:/var/lib/mysql
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysuperstrongpassword
     container_name: db_mysql
     networks:
       - db_backend
networks:
    db_backend:
      driver: bridge
      external: true


#worppess.yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
   #frontend
   wp_app:
     image: wordpress:latest
     restart: on-failure:3
     ports:
       - '49200:80'
       - '49201:443'
     volumes:
       - /volume1/docker/wp_app/wp_t:/var/www/html
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db_mysql:3306 //wrong entry? tried hostname, ip, service
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: mydb
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: myuser
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: mypassword
     networks:
       - db_backend
       - app_network  
networks:
#172.168.29.1/24
    db_backend:
      driver: bridge
      external: true
#172.168.30.1/24
    app_network:
      driver: bridge
      external: true
```

After all i was able to read about docker, docker-networking and docker compose i thought my solution should work, all can be deployed without any errors, except the database connection error :( ...

Is the way of connection the container between the networks correct?
May i edit the wp-config.php with the information and add them to the wordpress containe?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db_mysql:3306 with WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db

Comment: thanks for your answer. unfortunately it did not work. I continue receiving: This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at db. This could mean your host’s database server is down. where db changes i dependence to the Wordpress_host entry